# jQuery-file-upload - gets 400 bad request from AWS S3

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I'm following the instructions here for programmatic file upload:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API

I got my Files list by calling

```
var filesToUpload = $('#fileupload')[0].files
```

which returns an array like this:

```
FileList {0: File, 1: File, length: 2, item: function}
0:File
lastModified: 1413746649000
lastModifiedDate: Sun Oct 19 2014 12:24:09 GMT-0700 (PDT)
name: "Screen Shot 2014-10-19 at 11.26.56 AM.jpg"
size: 582848type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""

1: File
lastModified: 1413746649000
lastModifiedDate: Sun Oct 19 2014 12:24:09 GMT-0700 (PDT)
name: "Screen Shot 2014-10-19 at 11.27.08 AM.jpg"
size: 598589
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

Then I call:

```
var options = {url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/MYBUCKET',
    type: 'POST',
    formData: formDataOptions // my secret key, signature, etc. I know this is all correct
    }

    $('#fileupload').fileupload(); // initialization
    $('#fileupload').fileupload( // set options
    'option',
        {
            options
        }
    }
);

$('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: filesToUpload}); // add files
$('#fileupload').fileupload('send', {files: filesToUpload}); // send, no diff if I include filesToUpload again here
```

And I get back:

```
POST https://s3.amazonaws.com/MYBUCKET 400 (Bad Request)
```

Now, I KNOW my options and formParams are correct because I used the exact same configuration when doing the standard usage of fileupload() and it worked fine. I'm pretty sure the problem has something to do with the filesToUpload array I'm using. Though it has objects in them they are "File" objects, and sometimes when in the debugger for fileupload() (when using fileupload in the standard way) I noticed it has "Blob" objects instead. Do I need to somehow get "Blob" objects in order to submit this correctly? Or what else could it be?